# Light gridlines for already-existing axis

Tags: d3.js

**page.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208 -->
<style>
    #tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        width: 250px;
        z-index: 2;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .legend {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 60%;
    }

    #tooltip.hidden {
        display: none;
    }

    #tooltip p {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }
    g[class="col_1"] rect:hover {
        fill:#80061b;
    }
    g[class="col_2"] rect:hover {
        fill:#008394;
    }   
    div.slider-container {
      margin: 20px 20px 20px 80px;
    }
    div#month-slider {
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 300px;
      background:#e3eff4;
    }

    div#month-slider .ui-slider-handle {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .title {
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .grid line {
        stroke: lightgrey;
        stroke-opacity: 0.7;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .grid path {
        stroke-width: 0;
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/1.7.0/d3-legend.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
    <p><strong>Month: </strong><span id="month"></span><p>
    <p><strong><span id="sessionLabel"></span>: </strong><span id="sessionCount"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="slider-container">
  <span>Prior <strong><span id="value" class="value"></span></strong></span>
  <div id="month-slider">

  </div>
</div>

<script>
var margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 80},
    width = 1300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);


var g = svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// parse the date / time
// look at the .csv in Notepad! DO NOT LOOK AT EXCEL!
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");

var col_1 = "#CE1126",
    col_2 = "#00B6D0";

var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
          .range([col_1, col_2]); // red and blue 

var xMonthAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
              .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")); // label every month

var xYearAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
                  .ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1))
                  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")); // label every year

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d3.format('.2s')).tickSize(-width);

var formatNum = d3.format(",")

// load .csv file
d3.csv("test_data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}, function(error, data){
    if (error) throw error;

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var keys = data.columns.slice(1); 

    data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.date - a.date; });


    x.domain(d3.extent( data, function(d){ return d.date }) );

    var max = x.domain()[1];
    var min = x.domain()[0];
    var datePlusOneMonth = d3.timeDay.offset(d3.timeMonth.offset(max, 1), -1); // last day of current month: move up one month, back one day 

    x.domain([min,datePlusOneMonth]);

    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();
    z.domain(keys);

    // x-axis
    var monthAxis = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xMonthAxis);

    var defaultSliderValue = 25;

    d3.select("#value")
      .text(function(){
        if (defaultSliderValue == 1){
            return defaultSliderValue + " month"
        } else {
            return defaultSliderValue + " months"
        }
    });

    // calculate offset date based on initial slider value
    var offsetDate = defaultSliderValue ? d3.timeDay.offset(d3.timeMonth.offset((new Date(datePlusOneMonth.getFullYear(), datePlusOneMonth.getMonth()-defaultSliderValue)), 1), -1) : min
    // set x domain and re-render xAxis
    x.domain([offsetDate, datePlusOneMonth]);
    g.select('.x.axis').call(xMonthAxis);

    var filteredData = data.filter(function(d) { return d.date >= offsetDate; });   
    barWidth = (width - margin.right- margin.left)/(filteredData.length+1);    

    // the bars 
    g.append("g").classed('bars', true)
     .selectAll("g")
     .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(filteredData))
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr('class', function(d) { return d.key; })
     .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
     .selectAll("rect")
     .data(function(d) { return d; })
     .enter()
     .append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.date); })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
     .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
     .attr("width", barWidth)
     .on("mousemove", function(d) {

        //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
        var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[0]) + 88;
        var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[1]) + 64;
        var value = d.data[d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class')]; // differentiating between col1 and col2 values
        var valueClass = d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class');

        //Update the tooltip position and value
        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("left", xPosition + "px")
          .style("top", yPosition + "px")   

        d3.select("#tooltip")  
          .select("#sessionCount")
          .text(formatNum(value)); // return the value 

        d3.select("#tooltip")                    
          .select("#month")
          .text(d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")(d.data.date)); // return the value 

        d3.select("#tooltip")                    
          .select("#sessionLabel")
          .text(valueClass); // return the class 

        //Show the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);

      })
     .on("mouseout", function() {
        //Hide the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);

     });

    const firstDataYear = x.domain()[0];
    if (firstDataYear.getMonth() == 11){ // When .getmonth() == 11, this shows two years overlapping with each other, making the label look ugly
        const firstDataYearOffset = d3.timeDay.offset(firstDataYear, 1);
        var tickValues = x.ticks().filter(function(d) { return !d.getMonth()});
        if(tickValues.length && firstDataYearOffset.getFullYear() !== tickValues[1].getFullYear()) {
            tickValues = [firstDataYearOffset].concat(tickValues); 
        } else {
            tickValues = [firstDataYearOffset];
        }
    } else { 
        var tickValues = x.ticks().filter(function(d) { return !d.getMonth()});
        if(tickValues.length && firstDataYear.getFullYear() !== tickValues[0].getFullYear()) {
            tickValues = [firstDataYear].concat(tickValues); 
        } else {
            tickValues = [firstDataYear];
        }
    }

    xYearAxis.tickValues(tickValues);

    var yearAxis = g.append("g")
                     .attr("class", "yearaxis axis")
                     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 25) + ")")
                     .call(xYearAxis);

    var valueAxis = g.append("g")
                 .attr("class", "y axis")
                 .call(yAxis);

    monthAxis.selectAll("g").select("text")
      .attr("transform","translate(" + barWidth/2 + ",0)");

    // add the Y gridlines

    var options = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }).reverse();
    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
                    .data(options.slice().filter(function(type){ return type != "total"}))
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "legend")
                    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

    legend.append("rect")
          .attr("x", width - 18)
          .attr("width", 18)
          .attr("height", 18)
          .attr('class', function(d) { return d; })
          .style("fill", z)
          .on("mouseover", function(d){
                if (d == 'col_2') {
                    d3.selectAll(".col_2").style("fill", '#008394');
                }
                if (d == 'col_1') {
                    d3.selectAll(".col_1").style("fill", '#80061b');
                };

            })
           .on("mouseout", function(){
                d3.selectAll(".col_2").style("fill", col_2);
                d3.selectAll(".col_1").style("fill", col_1);
            })
           ;

    function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }

    legend.append("text")
          .attr("x", width - 24)
          .attr("y", 9)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text(function(d) { return capitalizeFirstLetter(d); });

    // Initialize jQuery slider
$('div#month-slider').slider({
    min: 1,
  max: 25,
  value: defaultSliderValue,
  create: function() {
    // add value to the handle on slider creation
    $(this).find('.ui-slider-handle').html($( this ).slider( "value" ));
  },
  slide: function(e, ui) {
    // change values on slider handle and label based on slider value   
    if (ui.value == 1){
        $('div.slider-container span.value').html(ui.value + ' month');
    } else { 
        $('div.slider-container span.value').html(ui.value + ' months');
    }
        $(e.target).find('.ui-slider-handle').html(ui.value);

    // calculate offset date based on slider value
    var offsetDate = ui.value ? d3.timeDay.offset(d3.timeMonth.offset((new Date(datePlusOneMonth.getFullYear(), datePlusOneMonth.getMonth()-ui.value)), 1), -1) : min
    // set x domain and re-render xAxis
    x.domain([offsetDate, datePlusOneMonth]);
    g.select('.x.axis').call(xMonthAxis);

    const firstDataYear = x.domain()[0];
    if (firstDataYear.getMonth() == 11){ // When .getmonth() == 11, this shows two years overlapping with each other, making the label look ugly
        const firstDataYearOffset = d3.timeDay.offset(firstDataYear, 1);
        var tickValues = x.ticks().filter(function(d) { return !d.getMonth()});
        if(tickValues.length == 2 && firstDataYearOffset.getFullYear() !== tickValues[1].getFullYear()) {
            tickValues = [firstDataYearOffset].concat(tickValues); 
        } else {
            tickValues = [firstDataYearOffset];
        }
    } else { 
        var tickValues = x.ticks().filter(function(d) { return !d.getMonth()});
        if(tickValues.length && firstDataYear.getFullYear() !== tickValues[0].getFullYear()) {
            tickValues = [firstDataYear].concat(tickValues); 
        } else {
            tickValues = [firstDataYear];
        }
    }
    xYearAxis.tickValues(tickValues);
    g.select('.yearaxis.axis').call(xYearAxis);


        // calculate filtered data based on new offset date, set y axis domain and re-render y axis
    var filteredData = data.filter(function(d) { return d.date >= offsetDate; });
    y.domain([0, d3.max(filteredData, function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();    
    g.select('.y.axis').transition().duration(200).call(yAxis);


    // re-render the bars based on new filtered data
    // the bars 
    var bars = g.select("g.bars")
     .selectAll("g")
     .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(filteredData));

     var barRects = bars.enter().append("g").merge(bars)
     .attr('class', function(d) { return d.key; })
     .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
     .selectAll("rect")
     .data(function(d) { return d; });

     barRects.exit().remove();

     barRects.enter()
     .append("rect");

   barWidth = (width - margin.right- margin.left)/(filteredData.length+1);     

   monthAxis.selectAll("g").select("text")
      .attr("transform","translate(" + barWidth/2 + ",0)");

     g.select("g.bars").selectAll('g rect')
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.date); })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
     .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
     .attr("width", barWidth)
     .on("mousemove", function(d) {

        //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
        var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[0]) + 88;
        var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[1]) + 64;
        var value = d.data[d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class')]; // differentiating between col1 and col2 values
        var valueClass = d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class');

        //Update the tooltip position and value
        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("left", xPosition + "px")
          .style("top", yPosition + "px")   

        d3.select("#tooltip")  
          .select("#sessionCount")
          .text(formatNum(value)); // return the value 

        d3.select("#tooltip")                    
          .select("#month")
          .text(d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")(d.data.date)); // return the value 

        d3.select("#tooltip")                    
          .select("#sessionLabel")
          .text(valueClass); // return the class 

        //Show the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
     })
     .on("mouseout", function() {
        //Hide the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
     });

  }
});

});

g.append("text")
   .attr("class", "title")
   .attr("x", (width / 2))             
   .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
   .text("Title");
</script>

</body>
```

**test_data.csv**:

```
date,col_1,col_2
11/1/2012,1977652,1802851
12/1/2012,1128739,948687
1/1/2013,1201944,1514667
2/1/2013,1863148,1834006
3/1/2013,1314851,1906060
4/1/2013,1283943,1978702
5/1/2013,1127964,1195606
6/1/2013,1773254,977214
7/1/2013,1929574,1127450
8/1/2013,1980411,1808161
9/1/2013,1405691,1182788
10/1/2013,1336790,937890
11/1/2013,1851053,1358400
12/1/2013,1472623,1214610
1/1/2014,1155116,1757052
2/1/2014,1571611,1935038
3/1/2014,1898348,1320348
4/1/2014,1444838,1934789
5/1/2014,1235087,950194
6/1/2014,1272040,1580656
7/1/2014,980781,1680164
8/1/2014,1391291,1115999
9/1/2014,1211125,1542148
10/1/2014,1020824,1782795
11/1/2014,1685081,926612
12/1/2014,1469254,1767071
1/1/2015,1168523,935897
2/1/2015,1602610,1450541
3/1/2015,1830278,1354876
4/1/2015,1275158,1412555
5/1/2015,1560961,1839718
6/1/2015,949948,1587130
7/1/2015,1413765,1494446
8/1/2015,1166141,1305105
9/1/2015,958975,1202219
10/1/2015,902696,1023987
11/1/2015,961441,1865628
12/1/2015,1363145,1954046
1/1/2016,1862878,1470741
2/1/2016,1723891,1042760
3/1/2016,1906747,1169012
4/1/2016,1963364,1927063
5/1/2016,1899735,1936915
6/1/2016,1300369,1430697
7/1/2016,1777108,1401210
8/1/2016,1597045,1566763
9/1/2016,1558287,1140057
10/1/2016,1965665,1953595
11/1/2016,1800438,937551
12/1/2016,1689152,1221895
1/1/2017,1607824,1963282
2/1/2017,1878431,1415658
3/1/2017,1730296,1947106
4/1/2017,1956756,1696780
5/1/2017,1746673,1662892
6/1/2017,989702,1537646
7/1/2017,1098812,1592064
8/1/2017,1861973,1892987
9/1/2017,1129596,1406514
10/1/2017,1528632,1725020
11/1/2017,925850,1795575
```

**Output**:

[image]

Two things I would like changed about this:

1) The y-axis grid lines should not be black, but the same color as what is at https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c506ac45617cf9ed39337f99f8511218, with CSS

```
.grid line {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

The ticks and y-axis themselves should remain black.

2) The grid line should not extend past the right end of the last bar above.

I already attempted the method in the link above, and the color is correct, but the hover events no longer work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things you need to do:

1. The class `grid` is missing from the axis. So add the class:

   ```
   var valueAxis = g.append("g")
       .attr("class", "y axis grid")
   ```
2. `yAxis` tickSize has to be changed to `.tickSize(-width+margin.left+margin.right)`

**Good catch!** It was due to the new CSS applied to `.grid path` which covers up the whole `svg`. Fixing that would be by adding `pointer-events: none;` to the same.

i.e.

```
.grid path {
    stroke-width: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```js
var dataAsCsv = `date,col_1,col_2
11/1/2012,1977652,1802851
12/1/2012,1128739,948687
1/1/2013,1201944,1514667
2/1/2013,1863148,1834006
3/1/2013,1314851,1906060
4/1/2013,1283943,1978702
5/1/2013,1127964,1195606
6/1/2013,1773254,977214
7/1/2013,1929574,1127450
8/1/2013,1980411,1808161
9/1/2013,1405691,1182788
10/1/2013,1336790,937890
11/1/2013,1851053,1358400
12/1/2013,1472623,1214610
1/1/2014,1155116,1757052
2/1/2014,1571611,1935038
3/1/2014,1898348,1320348
4/1/2014,1444838,1934789
5/1/2014,1235087,950194
6/1/2014,1272040,1580656
7/1/2014,980781,1680164
8/1/2014,1391291,1115999
9/1/2014,1211125,1542148
10/1/2014,1020824,1782795
11/1/2014,1685081,926612
12/1/2014,1469254,1767071
1/1/2015,1168523,935897
2/1/2015,1602610,1450541
3/1/2015,1830278,1354876
4/1/2015,1275158,1412555
5/1/2015,1560961,1839718
6/1/2015,949948,1587130
7/1/2015,1413765,1494446
8/1/2015,1166141,1305105
9/1/2015,958975,1202219
10/1/2015,902696,1023987
11/1/2015,961441,1865628
12/1/2015,1363145,1954046
1/1/2016,1862878,1470741
2/1/2016,1723891,1042760
3/1/2016,1906747,1169012
4/1/2016,1963364,1927063
5/1/2016,1899735,1936915
6/1/2016,1300369,1430697
7/1/2016,1777108,1401210
8/1/2016,1597045,1566763
9/1/2016,1558287,1140057
10/1/2016,1965665,1953595
11/1/2016,1800438,937551
12/1/2016,1689152,1221895
1/1/2017,1607824,1963282
2/1/2017,1878431,1415658
3/1/2017,1730296,1947106
4/1/2017,1956756,1696780
5/1/2017,1746673,1662892
6/1/2017,989702,1537646
7/1/2017,1098812,1592064
8/1/2017,1861973,1892987
9/1/2017,1129596,1406514
10/1/2017,1528632,1725020
11/1/2017,925850,1795575`;


var margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 80},
    width = 1300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);


var g = svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// parse the date / time
// look at the .csv in Notepad! DO NOT LOOK AT EXCEL!
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");

var col_1 = "#CE1126",
    col_2 = "#00B6D0";

var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
          .range([col_1, col_2]); // red and blue 

var xMonthAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
              .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")); // label every month

var xYearAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
                  .ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1))
                  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")); // label every year

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d3.format('.2s')).tickSize(-width+margin.left+margin.right);

var formatNum = d3.format(",")

var data = d3.csvParse(dataAsCsv, function(d, i, columns) {
   for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
});

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});

    var keys = data.columns.slice(1); 

    data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.date - a.date; });


    x.domain(d3.extent( data, function(d){ return d.date }) );

    var max = x.domain()[1];
    var min = x.domain()[0];
    var datePlusOneMonth = d3.timeDay.offset(d3.timeMonth.offset(max, 1), -1); // last day of current month: move up one month, back one day 

    x.domain([min,datePlusOneMonth]);

    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();
    z.domain(keys);

    // x-axis
    var monthAxis = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xMonthAxis);

    var defaultSliderValue = 25;

    d3.select("#value")
      .text(function(){
        if (defaultSliderValue == 1){
            return defaultSliderValue + " month"
        } else {
            return defaultSliderValue + " months"
        }
    });

    // calculate offset date based on initial slider value
    var offsetDate = defaultSliderValue ? d3.timeDay.offset(d3.timeMonth.offset((new Date(datePlusOneMonth.getFullYear(), datePlusOneMonth.getMonth()-defaultSliderValue)), 1), -1) : min
    // set x domain and re-render xAxis
    x.domain([offsetDate, datePlusOneMonth]);
    g.select('.x.axis').call(xMonthAxis);

    var filteredData = data.filter(function(d) { return d.date >= offsetDate; });   
    barWidth = (width - margin.right- margin.left)/(filteredData.length+1);    

    // the bars 
    g.append("g").classed('bars', true)
     .selectAll("g")
     .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(filteredData))
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr('class', function(d) { return d.key; })
     .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
     .selectAll("rect")
     .data(function(d) { return d; })
     .enter()
     .append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.date); })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
     .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
     .attr("width", barWidth)
     .on("mousemove", function(d) {

        //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
        var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[0]) + 88;
        var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[1]) + 64;
        var value = d.data[d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class')]; // differentiating between col1 and col2 values
        var valueClass = d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class');

        //Update the tooltip position and value
        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("left", xPosition + "px")
          .style("top", yPosition + "px")   

        d3.select("#tooltip")  
          .select("#sessionCount")
          .text(formatNum(value)); // return the value 

        d3.select("#tooltip")                    
          .select("#month")
          .text(d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")(d.data.date)); // return the value 

        d3.select("#tooltip")                    
          .select("#sessionLabel")
          .text(valueClass); // return the class 

        //Show the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);

      })
     .on("mouseout", function() {
        //Hide the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);

     });

    const firstDataYear = x.domain()[0];
    if (firstDataYear.getMonth() == 11){ // When .getmonth() == 11, this shows two years overlapping with each other, making the label look ugly
        const firstDataYearOffset = d3.timeDay.offset(firstDataYear, 1);
        var tickValues = x.ticks().filter(function(d) { return !d.getMonth()});
        if(tickValues.length && firstDataYearOffset.getFullYear() !== tickValues[1].getFullYear()) {
            tickValues = [firstDataYearOffset].concat(tickValues); 
        } else {
            tickValues = [firstDataYearOffset];
        }
    } else { 
        var tickValues = x.ticks().filter(function(d) { return !d.getMonth()});
        if(tickValues.length && firstDataYear.getFullYear() !== tickValues[0].getFullYear()) {
            tickValues = [firstDataYear].concat(tickValues); 
        } else {
            tickValues = [firstDataYear];
        }
    }

    xYearAxis.tickValues(tickValues);

    var yearAxis = g.append("g")
                     .attr("class", "yearaxis axis")
                     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 25) + ")")
                     .call(xYearAxis);

    var valueAxis = g.append("g")
                 .attr("class", "y axis grid")
                 .call(yAxis);

    monthAxis.selectAll("g").select("text")
      .attr("transform","translate(" + barWidth/2 + ",0)");

    // add the Y gridlines

    var options = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }).reverse();
    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
                    .data(options.slice().filter(function(type){ return type != "total"}))
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "legend")
                    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

    legend.append("rect")
          .attr("x", width - 18)
          .attr("width", 18)
          .attr("height", 18)
          .attr('class', function(d) { return d; })
          .style("fill", z)
          .on("mouseover", function(d){
                if (d == 'col_2') {
                    d3.selectAll(".col_2").style("fill", '#008394');
                }
                if (d == 'col_1') {
                    d3.selectAll(".col_1").style("fill", '#80061b');
                };

            })
           .on("mouseout", function(){
                d3.selectAll(".col_2").style("fill", col_2);
                d3.selectAll(".col_1").style("fill", col_1);
            })
           ;

    function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }

    legend.append("text")
          .attr("x", width - 24)
          .attr("y", 9)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text(function(d) { return capitalizeFirstLetter(d); });

    // Initialize jQuery slider
$('div#month-slider').slider({
    min: 1,
  max: 25,
  value: defaultSliderValue,
  create: function() {
    // add value to the handle on slider creation
    $(this).find('.ui-slider-handle').html($( this ).slider( "value" ));
  },
  slide: function(e, ui) {
    // change values on slider handle and label based on slider value   
    if (ui.value == 1){
        $('div.slider-container span.value').html(ui.value + ' month');
    } else { 
        $('div.slider-container span.value').html(ui.value + ' months');
    }
        $(e.target).find('.ui-slider-handle').html(ui.value);

    // calculate offset date based on slider value
    var offsetDate = ui.value ? d3.timeDay.offset(d3.timeMonth.offset((new Date(datePlusOneMonth.getFullYear(), datePlusOneMonth.getMonth()-ui.value)), 1), -1) : min
    // set x domain and re-render xAxis
    x.domain([offsetDate, datePlusOneMonth]);
    g.select('.x.axis').call(xMonthAxis);

    const firstDataYear = x.domain()[0];
    if (firstDataYear.getMonth() == 11){ // When .getmonth() == 11, this shows two years overlapping with each other, making the label look ugly
        const firstDataYearOffset = d3.timeDay.offset(firstDataYear, 1);
        var tickValues = x.ticks().filter(function(d) { return !d.getMonth()});
        if(tickValues.length == 2 && firstDataYearOffset.getFullYear() !== tickValues[1].getFullYear()) {
            tickValues = [firstDataYearOffset].concat(tickValues); 
        } else {
            tickValues = [firstDataYearOffset];
        }
    } else { 
        var tickValues = x.ticks().filter(function(d) { return !d.getMonth()});
        if(tickValues.length && firstDataYear.getFullYear() !== tickValues[0].getFullYear()) {
            tickValues = [firstDataYear].concat(tickValues); 
        } else {
            tickValues = [firstDataYear];
        }
    }
    xYearAxis.tickValues(tickValues);
    g.select('.yearaxis.axis').call(xYearAxis);


        // calculate filtered data based on new offset date, set y axis domain and re-render y axis
    var filteredData = data.filter(function(d) { return d.date >= offsetDate; });
    y.domain([0, d3.max(filteredData, function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();    
    g.select('.y.axis').transition().duration(200).call(yAxis);


    // re-render the bars based on new filtered data
    // the bars 
    var bars = g.select("g.bars")
     .selectAll("g")
     .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(filteredData));

     var barRects = bars.enter().append("g").merge(bars)
     .attr('class', function(d) { return d.key; })
     .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
     .selectAll("rect")
     .data(function(d) { return d; });

     barRects.exit().remove();

     barRects.enter()
     .append("rect");

   barWidth = (width - margin.right- margin.left)/(filteredData.length+1);     

   monthAxis.selectAll("g").select("text")
      .attr("transform","translate(" + barWidth/2 + ",0)");

     g.select("g.bars").selectAll('g rect')
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.date); })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
     .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
     .attr("width", barWidth)
     .on("mousemove", function(d) {

        //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
        var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[0]) + 88;
        var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[1]) + 64;
        var value = d.data[d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class')]; // differentiating between col1 and col2 values
        var valueClass = d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class');

        //Update the tooltip position and value
        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("left", xPosition + "px")
          .style("top", yPosition + "px")   

        d3.select("#tooltip")  
          .select("#sessionCount")
          .text(formatNum(value)); // return the value 

        d3.select("#tooltip")                    
          .select("#month")
          .text(d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")(d.data.date)); // return the value 

        d3.select("#tooltip")                    
          .select("#sessionLabel")
          .text(valueClass); // return the class 

        //Show the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
     })
     .on("mouseout", function() {
        //Hide the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
     });

  }
});

g.append("text")
   .attr("class", "title")
   .attr("x", (width / 2))             
   .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
   .text("Title");
```

```css
#tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        width: 250px;
        z-index: 2;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .legend {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 60%;
    }

    #tooltip.hidden {
        display: none;
    }

    #tooltip p {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }
    g[class="col_1"] rect:hover {
        fill:#80061b;
    }
    g[class="col_2"] rect:hover {
        fill:#008394;
    }   
    div.slider-container {
      margin: 20px 20px 20px 80px;
    }
    div#month-slider {
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 300px;
      background:#e3eff4;
    }

    div#month-slider .ui-slider-handle {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .title {
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .grid line {
        stroke: lightgrey;
        stroke-opacity: 0.7;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .grid path {
        stroke-width: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/1.7.0/d3-legend.min.js"></script>


<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
    <p><strong>Month: </strong><span id="month"></span><p>
    <p><strong><span id="sessionLabel"></span>: </strong><span id="sessionCount"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="slider-container">
  <span>Prior <strong><span id="value" class="value"></span></strong></span>
  <div id="month-slider">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But this seems to have disabled the tooltip (try mousing over a bar). Why is this?